# Openshift OKD 3.11 Install crashes during TASK [openshift_node : Install node, clients, and conntrack packages]

Tags: openshift, okd

I'm trying to install (containerized) Openshift 3.11 on a one master and three worker nodes. It always crashes at "TASK [openshift_node : Install node, clients, and conntrack packages]". The reason is that the master and all nodes can't resolve dns.

```
dig node01.onefloid.aws.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.2 <<>> node01.onefloid.aws.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 42234
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;node01.onefloid.aws.com.         IN      A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 10.107.190.160#53(10.107.190.160)
;; WHEN: Thu Nov 19 17:58:49 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 39
```

After the failed installation, I have to set the correct nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf again. The nameserver is provided by dhcp. Only the domain which is provided by dhcp differs. It's not '.onefloid.aws.com' It's 'eu-central-1.compute.internal'.

I tried an all in one installation on the master. It works.

Here is my stripped down inventory.

```
[masters]
master01.onefloid.aws.com

[nodes]
master01.onefloid.aws.com openshift_node_group_name='node-config-master-infra'
node01.onefloid.aws.com openshift_node_group_name='node-config-compute'
node02.onefloid.aws.com openshift_node_group_name='node-config-compute'
node03.onefloid.aws.com openshift_node_group_name='node-config-compute'

[etcd]
master01.onefloid.aws.com

[OSEv3:children]
masters
nodes
etcd

[OSEv3:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=root
openshift_deployment_type=origin
openshift_disable_check=memory_availability,disk_availability
ansible_service_broker_install=false
openshift_master_identity_providers=[{'name': 'htpasswd_auth','login': 'true', 'challenge': 'true','kind': 'HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider',}]
openshift_cluster_monitoring_operator_install=false
openshift_enable_service_catalog=false
```

Have someone an idea?